# Creating column data from multiple sources with varying formats in python

Tags: python

So as part of my code, I'm reading file paths that have varying names, but tend to stick to the following format

```
p(number)_(temperature)C
```

What I've done with those paths is separate it into 2 columns (along with 2 more columns with actual data) so I end up with a row that looks like this:

```
p2       18     some number     some number
```

However, I've found a few folders that use the following format:

```
p(number number)_(temperature)C
```

As it stands, for the first case, I use the following code to separate the file path into the proper columns:

```
def finale():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/Bashe/Desktop/12/'):
        file_name = os.path.join(root,"Graph_Info.txt")
        file_name_out = os.path.join(root,"Graph.txt")
        file = os.path.join(root, "StDev.txt")
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(root,"Graph_Info.txt")):
            with open(file_name) as fh, open(file) as th, open(file_name_out,"w") as fh_out:
                    first_line = fh.readline()
                    values = eval(first_line)
                    for value, line in zip(values, fh):
                        first_column = value[0:2]
                        second_column = value[3:5]
                        third_column = line.strip()
                        fourth_column = th.readline().strip()
                        fh_out.write("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (first_column, second_column, third_column, fourth_column))
        else:
            pass
```

I've played around with things and found that if I make the following changes, the program works properly.

```
first_column = value[0:3]
second_column = value[4:6]
```

Is there a way I can get the program to look and see what the file path is and act accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the fabulous world of regex.

```
import re


#..........
#case 0
if re.match(r"p\(\d+\).*", path) :
      #stuff
#case 1
elif re.match(r"p\(\d+\s\d+\).*", path):
      #other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for line in s.splitlines():
...    first,second = re.search("p([0-9 ]+)_(\d+)C",line).groups()
...    print first, " +",second
...
22  + 66
33 44  + 44
23 33  + 22
```